# Login to MSAL-enabled react frontend within Teams Tab App

Tags: microsoft-teams, msal-react

We have a react frontend utilizing MSAL to authenticate the user. Then we have a Teams Tab App which is a website to our react frontend. How do we allow Teams users (which already logged in to Teams Client) to access our react frontend without the need to login again to our react frontend?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible, but it requires you to configure SSO for your tab. Here are some starting points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-code

Incidentally, there's even a set of React controls for MSAL, making this even easier - see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react